# Can someone explain why my server/client don't work in a way they establish a connection?

Tags: perl

I'm beginning to work with sockets and trying to make a client and server, from which the client connects to the server without breaking contact after a message has been delivered to server or vice versa.

The problem that I have is that they both don't output anything (I can see the server is listening and client stops itself directly without outputting anything)

Both programs don't contain any lexical errors.

Here is the client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;

use Socket;

my $port = somedigits;
my $server_addr = "somebits\.somebits\.somebits\.somebits";
 
sub open_TCP
{
  # get parameters
  my ($FS, $server_addr, $port) = @_;
 
  my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
  socket($FS, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto);
  my $sin = sockaddr_in($port,inet_aton($server_addr));
  connect($FS,$sin) || return undef;
  
  my $old_fh = select($FS); 
  $| = 1;               # don't buffer output
  select($old_fh);
  1;
}
1;

&open_TCP;
```

Here is the server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;

use Socket;




my $port = somedigits;
my $server_addr = "somebits\.somebits\.somebits\.somebits";

socket(my $socket, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname("tcp")) or die $!; # initalize socket

bind($socket, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server_addr))) # associate socket with port
    or die("can't bind to port:" . $port);

listen($socket, 5) # start listening
    or die $1;
    
while(my $incoming_client = accept(my $new_socket, $socket)) { # accept incoming connections
    my $hostname = gethostbyaddr($incoming_client, AF_INET);
    sleep 2;
    print $new_socket "someoutput" . time() . "\n";
    printf("Connection from: $hostname");
    close $new_socket;
};
```

Comment: Tip: IO::Socket::IP makes this writing this kind of code easier and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the problem that I have is that they both don't output anything (I can see the server is listening and client stops itself directly without outputting anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the client, the sub's `$server_addr` is uninitialized since you don't pass any arguments to the sub.
- In the client, the sub's `$port` is uninitialized since you don't pass any arguments to the sub.
- Fix the above and it works. However, you might think it doesn't work because you don't flush your output. Using `printf("Connection from: $hostname\n");` is enough to do that when STDOUT is connected to a terminal.
- Finally,

  ```perl
  my $hostname = gethostbyaddr($incoming_client, AF_INET);
  ```

  should be

  ```perl
  my ($port, $packed_addr) = unpack_sockaddr_in($incoming_client);
  my $hostname = gethostbyaddr($packed_addr, AF_INET);
  ```
- By the way, the `if(!$incoming_client)` check is useless since you don't reach that statement if `$incoming_client` is false.

Comment: What changes do you suggest to realize your point 1 & 2 in your answer (comments are welcome)?

Comment: `sub open_TCP { my $server_addr, $port) = @_;  my $FS; ... } open_TCP($server_addr, $port);`

Answer (score 1):

Following samples demonstrate simple network *server* and *client*.

Sample of `server.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Socket;

my $server  = 'localhost';
my $port    = shift || 6000;
my $proto   = getprotobyname('tcp');

socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
    or die "Can't open socket $!";

bind(SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
    or die "Can't bind to port $port!";

listen(SOCKET, 5) or die "listen: $!";
say "SERVER: listen on $port";

while( my $client_addr = accept(NEW_SOCKET, SOCKET)) {
    my($port, $iaddr) = sockaddr_in($client_addr);
    my $name = gethostbyaddr($iaddr, AF_INET);
    my $ip   = inet_ntoa($iaddr);
    say "CLIENT: connection from $name $ip at port $port";
    print NEW_SOCKET "SERVER: localtime is " . localtime();
    close NEW_SOCKET;
}
```

Sample of `client.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Socket;

my $server  = shift || 'localhost';
my $port    = shift || 6000;
my $proto   = getprotobyname('tcp');

socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
    or die "Can't create a socket $!";
    
connect(SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
    or die "Can't connect to port $port!";
    
while( <SOCKET> ) {
    say;
}

close SOCKET or die "CLOSE: $!";
```

Recomendation: a quick visit to the following pages will assist you with programming

- [Sockets: Client/Server Communication](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc#Sockets:-Client/Server-Communication)
- [Perl - Socket Programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_socket_programming.htm)
- [IO::Socket](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO::Socket)
- [Network Programming with Perl](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3237)